# Как сделать замену в захваченном регуляркой тексте?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как можно произвести замены только по захваченному регуляркой тексту? Есть файл, где нужно поменять содержимое определённых тегов. Пример:

```
var str = "<tr><div id="test1">testtestet</div></tr><tr><div id="test2">testtestet</div></tr><tr><div id="test3">testtestet</div></tr>";

str = str.replace(/(<tr><div id=\"test2\">)(.*?)(<\/tr><\/div>)/g, '$1$2$3);
```

Мне нужно в содержимом второй группы (`$2` — `testtestest`), допустим, заменить буквы `t` На `т`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию обратного вызова в качестве аргумента замены:

```js
var str = '<tr><div id="test1">testtestet</div></tr><tr><div id="test2">testtestet</div></tr><tr><div id="test3">testtestet</div></tr>';
str = str.replace(/(<tr><div id="test2">)([^]*?)(<\/div><\/tr>)/g, function($0,$1,$2,$3) {
    return $1 + $2.replace(/t/g, 'т') + $3;
});
console.log(str);
```

`[^]*?` в поправленном шаблоне находит любые 0 и более символов, как можно меньше, включая символы перехода на новую строку. Можно также использовать `[\s\S]`, а в Chrome/Node.js уже можно и точку с модификатором `s` использовать:

```js
let str = '<tr><div id="test1">testtestet</div></tr><tr><div id="test2">test\ntest\net</div></tr><tr><div id="test3">testtestet</div></tr>';
str = str.replace(/(<tr><div id="test2">)(.*?)(<\/div><\/tr>)/sg, ($0,$1,$2,$3) => `${1}${$2.replace(/t/g, 'т')}${3}`);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Я всё-таки не совсем понял, чем отличается ваш вариант от `.*?`. Это ведь тоже не-жадная последовательность любых символов или её отсутствие (0 символов)?

Comment: @Turambar `.*?` не найдёт символов CR, LF.